# Binary Search Tree and height

Tags: binary-search-tree

Hello for our assignment, we were supposed to creat BST with input in following order:
Victor, Zebra, Hotel, Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, India, Zebra, Xray

So our program did its thing and got
[initial image of bst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpUI8.jpg)

And then it asked us to remove first India and then Victor from the tree.

And we got
[Tree after removing two nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3TFF.jpg)

And then it asked us for the height of alpha bravo and charlie and we said it was alpha - 2, bravo - 1 and charlie - 0

But the answer was alpha - 1, bravo - 0 and charlie - 2

Is our visualization of bst wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your visualisation is correct.

You should note that it is more typical to refer to a binary tree as having a height and each node in a binary tree having a certain 'depth' - that is, the root has depth 0 in the tree. In this example, 'Hotel' has depth 0 and 'Charlie' has depth 3. The first tree you posted has an overall height of 4. The second tree has an overall height 3.